# Tableau Desktop Inside Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a Tableau Desktop executable inside the Tableau server installation.

I have a system where Tableau server in Cloud and would want to use Tableau Desktop in the same server? Is that feasible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tableau Server and Desktop are two different products and Server does not ship with a copy of Desktop.

They **can** both be installed on the same windows machine, but I would **never** do that except for trouble-shooting reasons (ideally you should install Tableau Server on a dedicated machine so that it does not have to fight anything else for resources).

Answer (score 3):

Tableau Server lets you make limited edits to existing workbooks, but you can not create new workbooks directly.

However, if you want to install Tableau Desktop separately, on the same cloud server that hosts your Tableau Server, it may (or may not) be doable depending on the specifications of the cloud server.

Answer (score 3):

**The major difference between Tableau desktop and Tableau Server?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

At my previous organization, we always had a desktop version installed on the VM running our tableau server. This was useful for making connections to data sources that required firewall rules since the VM's IP was static. Then extracts could scheduled for refreshes.

So yes, it is feasable, but like others, it is a separate product.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: make sure you understand the implications of editing an existing view.

Workbook owner, project owner or site admin may grant you rights to do the editing. However, you will be overwriting the existing workbook (you can't "save as...")

Besides, the edit function on the server is limited to visualization (sheets) and doesn't work with dashboards (to be improved in the next release, as announced)

Answer (score 1):

Tableau Desktop  and tableau server are two different product.
Both have their different executable files.
Desktop is created for development purposes while server is created for more sharing and authentications purposes.
You can do some edits in server, but you cannot create a new dashboard on server.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, Tableau Desktop and Server are separate products and have separate executable. We used to have Tableau desktop installed on Server to publish extracts and manage our extracts which were developed using API

Answer (score 0):

Another thought: Tableau Server provides permissioned users with the ability to leverage Web Authoring to create/edit server content. Web authoring has the same look/feel as desktop, and has most of the features.

Many go this route as it comes with your server license, so the additional desktop purchase is not necessary.
[More Info Here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/server-desktop-web-edit-differences.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In my current project both Tableau Server and Tableau Desktop are hosted on sane server. You need to analyse the data volume, traffic to workbooks to come up with right RAM size. I would recommend minimum RAM of 25GB assuming close to 20 users accessing tableau server and there is not huge volume of data refresh or connectivity

Answer (score 0):

The desktop version  "inside server" is to create and explore licenses. If you have one of these, you can create a sheet/dashboard using the Tableau Server through your browser.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.